# MPI mpirun execvp error on file -np : no such file or directory

Tags: mpi

I am trying to run this using MPI as follows:

```
mpirun  –np  16 ./wrf.exe &
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
[proxy:0:0@dharmsai] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file –np (No such file or directory)
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: The  `–` in `–np` isn't the normal hyphen/minus `-`. It's a unicode en-dash. Use `-` instead.

Comment: @muru Well spotted. Larger lesson: never copy commandlines from Word/Pdf files.